# Type 'Background.Type' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 2 swift files:

***ContentView.swift***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {

                Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                SetBackground
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the swiftui view file I created called:

***Background.swift***

```
struct SetBackground: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Capsule()
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 1.7)
                .offset(x: geometry.size.width * -0.1 , y: geometry.size.height * -0.9)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to call the file Background in the 1st code, I get the error:
`Type 'SetBackground.Type' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`

Why is this and how could I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `View` by initializing the object rather than using the `SetBackground` type.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dataStore = [0, 1, 2]
    @State var a = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {

                Color.white.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                SetBackground() <---- add "()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SetBackground` is on another file, not on the main `ContentView` file, I can't call it using `()`, I would if it were on the same file...

Comment: I separated `SetBackground` into another file and it is still working for me. Xcode 11.4. Can you provide a little bit more context?

Comment: let me double check, this is weird